# How do I boot Windows 10 without Secure Boot (but with UEFI enabled) if it was preinstalled with Secure Boot?

Tags: linux, windows-10, grub, grub2, secure-boot

I'm trying to get Windows 10 to play nice in a dual-boot setup with Antergos as the other OS, but I don't want to have to toggle Secure Boot every time I want to switch OSes, and I'd much rather not have to go through the hugely inconvenient and cumbersome process of reinstalling GRUB with Secure Boot keys, `shim`, `efitools` and all the works. Is there any way to get Windows to boot in UEFI mode without Secure Boot if it was installed with Secure Boot?

As it is, if I boot Windows from the GRUB menu, it shows the Windows logo for several seconds and then suddenly reboots. If I enable Secure Boot, Windows boots into recovery mode after a Secure Boot error, but I can click the normal boot option which causes the PC to reboot and show the message *again*, but then Windows boots perfectly normally afterwards. And then I have to go back in the BIOS if I want to switch from Windows to Antergos.

I'm on an Alienware 15 R2.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem by disabling legacy boot/BIOS support in the BIOS menu. Windows 10 now boots normally and without errors.

Comment: Hmm my Asus Zephyrus doesn't seem to have such an option in the BIOS.